# I can not delete directory on server

Tags: php, permissions, filesystems

Accidentally I created the folder on remotely server as `mkdir("folder_name",0);` now I can not delete this folder from server. I think this is from permission, because `0` is not correct permission.

So, now how can I delete this folder from server ?

P.S. I use aptana sudio as FTP client

Answer (score 0):

Try first to change the permission to something suitable 777 and try again to delete it

Answer (score 0):

In your server, you can use [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to change permissions and [rmdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) to remove directory :

```
chmod("folder_name", 0777);
rmdir("folder_name");
```

Comment: When I use `chmod` for this folder, php returns: `Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Unable to access ... `

Comment: Youps, then try to change your directory permissions to `0700` at least... and if you can't, you'll need to connect using ssh or sftp to your remote host to change those permissions...... can't help more :-o sorry.